# Java - JAXB forces XML-node to ElementNSImpl datatype

Tags: java, jaxb, deserialization, unmarshalling

I have following QueryResult object class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="QueryResult", namespace = "")
public class QueryResult {

    public QueryResult()
    {
        this.attachments = new ArrayList<QueryAttachment>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Error")
    protected QueryError error;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected Element content;
}
```

And I want to unmarshall following queryResultXml variable which is a jdom.Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QueryResult xmlns:func="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:functions" xmlns:meta="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1" xmlns:er="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:Byggeskadefondendokument:1">
    <er:Byggeskadefondendokumenter meta:key="MetadatKey">
        <er:EftersynsrapportIndikator meta:key="MetadatKey/1">false</er:EftersynsrapportIndikator>
        <er:ByggeskadefondendokumentSamling meta:key="MetadatKey/2" />
    </er:Byggeskadefondendokumenter>
</QueryResult>
```

I am using following code in order to unmarshall:

```
QueryResult result = XmlHelper.parseGenericObjectFromXmlString(new XMLOutputter().outputString(queryResultXml), QueryResult.class)
```

The parseGenericObjectFromXmlString method:

```
static <T> T parseGenericObjectFromXmlString(String xml, Class<T> genericType) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(genericType)
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller()

        def obj = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml))
        return obj
    }
```

JAXB then throws following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element

at diadem.dirigent.plugin.integration.QueryResult$JaxbAccessorF_content.set(FieldAccessor_Ref.java:45)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.receive(Accessor.java:151)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:597)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at diadem.base.plugin.helpers.XmlHelper.parseGenericObjectFromXmlString(XmlHelper.groovy:22)
at diadem.dirigent.plugin.IntegrationService.getResult(IntegrationService.groovy:95)
at diadem.dirigent.plugin.IntegrationService.callSourceSystem(IntegrationService.groovy:65)
at diadem.dirigent.plugin.IntegrationService.processQueryInput(IntegrationService.groovy:36)
at diadem.dirigent.plugin.IntegrationService.processQueryInput(IntegrationService.groovy:24)
at diadem.dirigent.plugin.IntegrationServiceSpec.test Integration processQuery with Byggeskadefond query definition(IntegrationServiceSpec.groovy:105)
```

JAXB automatically forces the QueryResult.Content property to ElementNSImpl, but why does it not map the unmarshalled content to Element datatype instead ?. Does JAXB do that for all properties with @XmlAnyElement annotation ?.

Answer (score 0):

The exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element
```

tells you that you used the wrong `Element` class in

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
protected Element content;
```

Obviously you used `org.jdom.Element`. But instead you need to use `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

This is described in the *Usages* examples in the [Javadoc of `@XmlAnyElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html). Notice especially the `Element` links given there and to where they are pointing.

> **Usages:**
>
> @XmlAnyElement
>   public [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)[] others;
>
> // Collection of [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) or JAXB elements.
>   @XmlAnyElement(lax="true")
>   public Object[] others;
>
> @XmlAnyElement
>    private List<[Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)> nodes;
>
> @XmlAnyElement
>   private [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) node;

JAXB uses the class `ElementNSImpl` which is an implementation of the interface `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

Comment: `JAXB uses the class ElementNSImpl which is an implementation of the interface org.w3c.dom.Element.`: it seems [it's not true](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementNSImpl.html).

Comment: @MarcoSulla I don't understand your objection. Your link to the javadoc of ElementNSImpl says: *All Implemented Interfaces: ..., [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html),...*

Comment: Mh. Senility? :D